# meromorphic extension of dirichlet series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Suppose $\{a(n)\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a bounded complex sequence. Let $\phi(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$. Obviously, the Dirichlet series $\phi(s)$ is absolutely convergent for $\mathcal{R}(s)>1$. I would like to know the minimal value $\alpha$ such that the Dirichlet series $\phi(s)$ can have a meromorphic extension on the half plane $\mathcal{R}(s)>\alpha$? The converse question is whether there is some condition that ensures the Dirichlet series $\phi(s)$ can have a meromorphic extension on the half plane $\mathcal{R}(s)>1/2$?

Comment: This question is way too broad; one cannot do better than $\alpha = 1$ without some conditions on $\{a(n)\}$.

Answer (score 8):

The maximal domain of meromorphic continuation of a Dirichlet series can be anything.

More precisely, for every connected open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{C}$, which contains the half plane $\{\Re s>1\}$, there exists a Dirichlet series $D$ with bounded coefficients, which is holomorphic in $O$, cannot be extended continuously beyond $O$, and all isolated points of $\mathbb{C}\setminus O$ are simple poles of $D$.

If $O$ is simply connected, and is contained in the half plane $\{\Re s>\frac{1}{3}\}$, you can arrange $D$ to have an Euler product.

Comment: Citations along with these statements would be very welcome!

Comment: @Greg Martin: Bhowmik, Schlage-Puchta: The maximal domain of meromorphic continuation of a Dirichlet series, Analysis 26 (2010)